# Passing class name to super class constructor in Scala via reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, constructor

How can I pass the name of a class to its super class constructor and is it even possible? I'm thinking about something like this:

```
class TestClass extends SuperTestRequiringName(TestClass.getClass.getName) {}
```

This would be better than passing the name as a hard-coded string because consistency is preserved during rename refactorings.

Even better would be the actual runtime class so I would get the name of a subclass if possible. But this doesn't work as well:

```
class TestClass extends SuperTestRequiringName(this.getClass.getName) {}
```

I'm not asking how to access the subclass name inside the super class at runtime in general. It is important that the class name is available as a super constructor argument so the super class can pass it along to its own super class (from a library I can't change).

Comment: Although there are some good answers to the question, the question itself is a sign that most probably you are doing something wrong. First of all, the code in the base class always can get the name of the class it really in just by using `this.getClass`. `this` never lies! Another problem is that if you are using the sub-class name for anything other than logging, most probably you are doing something wrong as well. If the library asks name of the class, maybe it asks for some other class name? To sum up: show us your real problem and there might be a better solution to it that this.

Comment: @SergGr I'm writing an abstract test class that is supposed to reuse some heavy-weight objects like an `ActorSystem` per concrete subclass and only shut them down in the `afterAll` hook (using the `OneInstancePerTest` trait, so I would create one per test case otherwise). To name the `ActorSystem` and generally have a unique reference for each subclass I thought it would be reasonable to just use the class name. Since I inherit from another abstract class that receives the `ActorSystem` as a constructor argument, I need to create it right there.

Comment: I updated the question to explicitly state that I'm interested in the name of the runtime class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your problem has a good solution as is. The way JVM memory model works, you can't use `this` before the call to the base constructor, even to get your own class name. If the reason you inherit from the library's class is to re-use its functionality, rather than the need to actually use your classes in the same contexts the base class is used, I'd suggest replacing inheritance with [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) which is the right solution for such a problem anyway. The code would go like this:

```
case class Wrapper(s: String)

class LibraryClass(val w: Wrapper) {
  def someUsefulStuff(n: Int): String = ???

  def someNotUsefulStuff(n: Int): String = ???
}

class Base() {
  private val delegate:LibraryClass = new LibraryClass(Wrapper(this.getClass.getName))

  // expose useful methods from the delegate
  // depending on logic maybe decorate them as protected
  def someUsefulStuff(n: Int): String = delegate.someUsefulStuff(n)
}

class LeafA extends Base

class LeafB extends Base
```

See this example [online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/laGUgoOcTJaLMf83kKiyYQ).

If you really need to inherit from the `LibraryClass` to be used in those contexts, you probably will have to make your subclasses pass the string explicitly as in @ygor solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
class TestClass extends SuperTestRequiringName(classOf[TestClass].getName)
```

In Scala `classOf[A]` is the same as `A.class` in Java.

`getClass` is a method, which you only can call on instances of classes.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. However, having access to the actual runtime class name (there might be a further subclass) would be even better. I updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand your question or not but you can use `ClassTag` for this purpose. For example;

```
import scala.reflect._
class SuperTestRequiringName(name: String) {}
class TestClass extends SuperTestRequiringName(classTag[TestClass].runtimeClass.getName)
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this solves the consistency problem when renaming. @ygor posted a similar solution. It is a bit shorter. In my understanding it yields the same name,doesn't it? I updated my question to further specify that I'm actually interested in the runtime class name (potential subclass).